# MSHTML MFC Tutorial

Tags: mfc, visual-c++, mshtml

I know this has been asked twice before but both had no proper replies and are dated so in case someone has found something in these days, I'm asking again!.

Any one knows any good tutorial for MSHTML or some open source project which can be read to understand how various operations can be done in  MSHTML - MFC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question makes it difficult to know exactly what you are trying to do, but the main MFC class that you need to use is `CHtmlView`. The MSDN has the definitive sources of information about it:

- [CHtmlView class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42h6dke4%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [Creating a Web
  Browser-Style MFC Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcbhy332%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [Using MFC to Host a WebBrowser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752046%28VS.85%29.aspx)

If you find those links a bit terse, then this page contains some slightly friendlier articles:

- [Advanced CHtmlView Hosting](http://ehsanakhgari.org/article/visual-c/advanced-chtmlview-hosting)

However, I would also ask whether you are definitely 100% sure that you want to use MFC?

The reason I ask is because I've worked for a number of years on an open-source project that hosts the Microsoft WebBrowser control and we saw significant performance improvements when we stripped out MFC from the project. The MFC abstractions weren't really buying us anything over the COM interfaces that are exposed by the control. Stripping out the MFC also made our code much simpler.

The project is open source, so if you want to see the code for yourself, you can get more information [here](http://code.google.com/p/ubx/). It is specifically the [LibRender](http://code.google.com/p/ubx/source/browse/#svn/trunk/LibRender) project that hosts the WebBrowser control. If you want to see it running, you should build the [SWViewer](http://code.google.com/p/ubx/source/browse/#svn/trunk/SWViewer) solution.

Answer (score 1):

The one place I like to visit for MFC is Newcomer's [site](http://www.flounder.com) There are some useful tutorials and demos of various things there. Although its more of a general MFC site, so maybe you can find what you are looking for there.